# Scale div into div like background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scale

I'm working on a web app and now facing a rather tricky task.
I have an image that I have to add overlay for.

Let's say I have an image of a car. I need to add values, like outside and inside temperature, on top of the car image.

It would be easy to add fixed pixel offsets for those temperature labels, but the image need to be scalable to every screen height and width-wise. I can't think of easy way to scale div into div exactly as "background-size:contain;" does for images.

Could someone point me to right tracks before I write complex javascript scaling logic?

Comment: Scaling logic? just use percentage widths in your CSS.

Comment: That doesn't work as "background-size:contain;" makes image resize depending on image aspect ration and container width and height. css offset in % doesn't do the trick, at least not the way I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Since you haven't included any of your code, there's lots of ways to interpret this question. But with images, you can do `width:100%; height:auto` and it will scale proportionally.

Comment: Please provide the code to your specific problem. *As such, your question is too broad and hence can have a plethora of answers based on the reader's interpretation of the question.*

Comment: One of the things you should clarify is if your image is a `<img />` or a `<div></div>`. The answers would most likely vary depending on your tag (since an `<img />` cannot have child nodes). It sounds like it's a `<div>`, but clarification or the code you currently have written (or mock code if you don't have anything written) would aid other.

Comment: updated my answer, added CSS that may help a lot with modern browsers. you may avoid lots of calculations with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ww = window width
wh = window height
ow = Original Width of your image
oh = Original Height of your image
nw = New Width of your image
nh = New Height of your image
mt = Margin top to adjust image to the screen vertically
ox = overlay location x coordinate according to original size of the image
oy = overlay location y coordinate according to original size of the image
nox = New ox
noy = new oy
sf = scaling factor
```

based on screen size you'll have a scaling factor for your image.

```
sf = ww / ow -> we find our scaling factor
nh = oh * sf -> then calculate our new image height
mt = (oh - nh) / 2 -> amount we need to shift image up to center screen
nox = ox * sf -> new overlay x coordinate
noy = (oy * sf) - mt -> new overlay y coordinate
```

**edit**

if image is too wide then this logic needs to be adjusted to shift image horizontally not vertically

**edit 2**

If you're targeting modern browsers only, then you can use `CSS` `transform:  scale(sx[, sy]);` . This will re-size your **`DIV` and all it's content proportionally** Use `transform: scale()` with `transform-origin: 0 0;` to re-size from top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SVG image this would be easy:
http://css-tricks.com/svg-text-typographic-designs/

Here is two examples with CSS:

1. `http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zxqdev`
2. `http://maketea.co.uk/2013/12/16/smooth-text-overlays-with-css-transforms.html`

Answer (score 0):

I'm never tested CSS3 **object-fit** , but I think it's very useful for your solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-object-fit-object-position/